# ¿Cómo limitar a un solo comentario por día para cada dirección IP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario para agregar comentarios que se guardan en mi base de datos según producto.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se permita un solo comentario por IP cada dia? Osea, si la IP ya hizo un comentario en las últimas 24 horas, esa IP no debería poder comentar de nuevo.

Comment: registrar la ip del cliente que origina cada comentario, validar una tabla de registros únicos y comparar allí si hay registro para el día. O añádir el campo con la IP a la tabla de comentarios y crear una vista para buscar sólo la ip y el timestamp de los comentarios. Hay varias aproximaciones

Answer (score 0):

Una de muchas soluciones puede ser almacenar la ip del usuario/cliente con $_server[''remote_addr'] en un tabla en tu bd y hacer la comparación cuando se haga un nuevo comentario.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones no se ajustan al formato del sitio y terminan cerradas, por favor evita responderlas